# How to catch all http request errors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, http, dom

Above all, poor English, feel free to correct.

Is there any ways to catch all http request errors caused by DOM(e.g. broken URL of `<link>`, `<img>` etc.) or ajax in JavaScript?

I've tried `window.onerror`, but it seems that it just supports catching JavaScript runtime errors, not including http request errors.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try to use debugging tool such as firebug !

Comment: @crypticous because I want to collect those errors and send them to server on clients.

Comment: your web server usually keeps a log of the 404s it generates

Comment: .ajaxError() https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/ , might be helpful on ajax request.

Comment: @DavidFregoli I can't catch all because some link refer to cross origin server.

Comment: @Pravat\ Maskey @V31 I can use jQuery, but some errors are not caused our code but third part library like socket.io-client. And I need the errors too.

Comment: nice, did you try with jquery error function mentioned on http://api.jquery.com/error/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .ajaxSetup for the normal http calls like:

Code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
      cache: false,
      error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
          if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            //Some code here
          } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            //Some code here
          } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            //Some code here
          } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            //Some code here
          } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            //Some code here
          } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            //Some code here
          } else {
          }
      }
  });
```

For third party errors like socket.io you need to handle it separately like:

```
socket.on('error', function() {
   //here i change options
   socket = io.connect(host, options);
```

});

Comment: `.ajaxError()` is much more straightforward